# Visualise 2D layer to pseudo 3D via QGIS Geometry Generator

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I would like to visualise a 2D object to pseudo 3D via QGIS Geometry Generator

I have a polygonal layer of a football field (GPKG format):

[image]

I use this polygonal layer for a sports analytics project (heatmaps):

[image]

I would like to apply the Geometry Generator to visualize this layer with this perspective:

[image]

And use the same expression to translate the points (points layer) that I digitise to represent the shootings

Comment: Have a look at the qgis2threejs plugin.

Comment: Do you really want to use QGIS Geometry Generator or do you want to get a  pseudo 3D view ? if the later you could just use the native "3D map view" (https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/3d_map_view.html)

Comment: I think my requirement is simpler, but maybe its development with Geometry Generator is more complex. I don't need to generate a dynamic scene. I need to get a static visualisation. I have seen that Geometry Generator has functions like `translate` that allows to make an extrusion of a polygon layer, but I don't know if it has functions to make a perspective change.

Comment: I definitely think geometry generator is not the way to go. The only lines that are actually protruded appear to be the goal posts. Everything else is essentially flat. I agree that you would be better off using the native 3D map view - have a try with your existing rectangle polygons and tilt the view. You should be 90% of the way there. Maybe you just need the goalpost polygon to have an extrusion value and configure a 3D style for that layer accordingly.

Comment: 100% agree. I think I have mistaken the approach in thinking that with Geometry Generator could create a perspective shifting effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Layer Style* → *Drawing Effects* → *Draw options* → *Effect Properties*

Within the *Effect Properties* options, expand the *Effecte Type* and select *Transform*. Test the parameters to your liking to get the pseudo 3D view.

It works with vector layers (points, lines, polygons). It is compatible with Geometry Generator, but it is not compatible with Heatmap renderer:

**Original layer**
[image]

**Transform Layer**
[image]